# Wireless network connection help on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have all the drivers I need for my Ubuntu 12.04, but whenever I start up my computer it says there's no networks available. I go into additional drivers and it says there's a Broadcom one available, so I click download. Then it gives some error about not being able to get the driver, and then all of a sudden, the wireless works. It's just a minor inconvenience at the moment, but I'm wondering if there's some way to fix this so I don't have to do this every time I start up the laptop.

Comment: When you are trying to download the driver using `additional drivers` are you connected with at least a cable (Ethernet cable) to the internet? If not, do this and see if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do from a terminal: `ifconfig WIRELESSDEVICE down` and then `ifconfig WIRELESSDEVICE up`.
If you don't know the device name use `iwconfig` (it's wlanNUMBER).
If, after that (it's a highly unprofessional solution), the device finds your AP, this is a problem with the card internal configuration which can be resolved in two ways:

- Use `wicd` of another network manager wich brings the interface down & up at the system startup;
- Create a simple .sh script with this inside:

  ifconfig WIRELESSDEVICE down
  ifconfig WIRELESSDEVICE up

...and execute it after the boot manually or by editing the [boot sequence](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_the_meaning_of_the_runlevel).
**Important note**: install **only** the drivers you need for you **exact** model, use a packet manager (I *suggest* `synaptics` or `aptitude`) to find the correct driver manually if the system can't suggest a good driver.
If you can't resolve the problem, before tweaking, fully upgrade your system to the latest version with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.
**Important note 2**: do not alter the kernel packages (*linux-**), but if you have an old kernel try booting with it if you have a problem, in some cases it can help.
If you have other problems don't hesitate to write here. Have a nice experience.